# Uniqueness of shortest distance between the center of two circles (and in higher dimensions)

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

I am an EE presently writing a book on microwave semiconductors. In one of the common graphs we employ - the Smith chart - we use the bilinear transformation to map rectangular regions to circles in the transformed domain. Does anyone from the math world know of a simple proof to demonstrate the uniqueness of the line connecting the centers of two arbitrary circles that is everywhere orthogonal to the tangent points of the associated contours? And, is there a way to extend this to higher dimensions.

Thanks so much...

John Sevic

Comment: I don't think you are using bilinear maps to map rectangles to circles, because bilinear maps simply can't do that. Are you maybe using fractional linear maps?

Comment: ---the line connecting the centers of two arbitrary circles that is everywhere orthogonal to the tangent points of the associated contours?--- Do you mind explaining your terminology a bit? It should be very straightforward business, but the expressions like "a line orthogonal to a point" turn it all into an undecipherable riddle :-).

Comment: Maybe the lines are field lines, and not actually straight lines? Otherwise there is only one line through the two centers, because a line is completely determined by two points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We define the impedance plane as the semi-infinite region R>0 and -inf<X<+inf and transform impedance, Z = R+jX, through gamma = (Z-Zr)/(Z+Zr). This transformation yields a family of circles bounded by the circle R < 1, i.e. the entire semi-infinite half-plane maps to the interior of the unit circle, and its boundary, for R=0. As far as I know, they're linear maps, c.f. Churchill, Section 66 of the 5th edition, where he calls them bilinear transformations (and linear fractional transformations). Am I missing something?

Comment: Let me expand on my (poor) vocabulary: consider a pair of functions, represented by their contours, that appear as circles after being transformed by the bilinear transform. Each contour from the first function will, at some point, be tangent to a contour from the other function. I am interested in the properties of the line that is everywhere orthogonal to this tangency point. I can plot this line by hand and plot it numerically, and it reminds me of a geodesic (i.e. it's not a straight line, in general). I'm interesting in proving the line is unique. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably hire a mathematician.

However, taking the Smith chart as the standard unit circle in the complex plane, the mapping
$$  f(z) = \frac{z + 1}{i z - i}  $$
takes the open disc to the upper half plane. It takes the geodesics meeting $1$ to vertical lines, that is constant real part. It takes the horocycles tangent to the circle at $1$ to horocycles with constant imaginary part. The inverse mapping is
$$  g(z) = \frac{i z + 1}{i z - 1}.    $$

I notice some images of a Smith chart take $-1$ as the important point instead.One may simply negate everything in this version to rotate the disc by $180^\circ.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Yes, 180° is a short circuit and 0° is an open circuit. Maybe I should post the image from by book to illustrate what I'm after. Thanks for your post.

Comment: @JohnSevic, yes, you should post your image, and probably some pages from the book by Churchill you mention.

Comment: I've tried to attach a couple of figures, but my code does not seem to work. Any recommendations?

Comment: @JohnSevic, what I do is save a pdf or jpeg on my home computer, usually a jpeg as the result is better. One of the edit options is an icon of a painting. Click on that, it lets you browse your home computer for the filename of the image. Then click on upload. Or, I could paste them into your question if you emailed them to me. There seems to be an upper bound on jpeg file size for upload, perhaps six megabyte each. Click on my name for email addresses.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your graciousness in helping me out on this. I chatted with a Professor in our math department (here at UC Santa Cruz) and we constructed a simple proof based on convexity. It turns out if one of the contour sets is strictly convex, e.g. a circular level contours, then the trajectory that is everywhere orthogonal to the tangent points is indeed unique. Thanks again...